# Why does git flag files as changed when only the line endings are changed and normalization is on?

Tags: git, line-endings

Case1:
  windows core.autocrlf=true
when I change the line endings of a text file to lf these are marked as changes. But they are all normalized when committed so there shouldn't be any changes.

Case2:
  linux core.autocrlf=input
when I change the line endings of a text file to crlf these are marked as changes. But they are all normalized when committed so there shouldn't be any changes.

So why does git flag files as changed when only the line endings are changed and normalization is on?

Answer (score 0):

From the git documentation regarding `autocrlf`:

> Git can handle this by auto-converting CRLF line endings into LF when you add a file to the index, and vice versa when it checks out code onto your filesystem.

This is what it the option does, in a nutshell. It does not pervade every single operation of git, only `git add` and `git checkout` (and similar, i.e., `git reset` and probably others that change your working directory).

You might want to look into the `text` attribute in `.gitattributes`; maybe that's closer to what you need.

Comment: what i need is a way commit the line endings that i want without 'changes/conflicts' and checkout with line endings specified in a config file.

Comment: I'd suggest you try `.gitattributes => text`, it will probably do what you want.